# Resistors calibration about tolerance

Tags: resistors

Would it ever be possible to find a value of resistor that is outside the stated tolerance?

kindly help, practically is it possible?

Comment: Dear new user, welcome to EE.SE! To help us answer your question, would you please provide more information? What's the context of your question? How will an answer to your question help you? Having said that, in Statistics nothing is 100%. If you get a large enough sample you will get one resistor out of the tolerance range.

Comment: @Ali  Have you heard about a wonderful device called an *Ohm meter* ?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Although practically, if a resistor fresh from the factory measures wrong, it's probably the meter needing a battery or the meter has suffered something like being plugged into the mains on "Ohms" function.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. It could be broken physically, overloaded (cooked), it could be faulty from the factory, it could have the sum of initial tolerance, lifetime drift and other factors which could add to more than the stated tolerance. Happens all the time.

From a recent post here:

[image]

I have also observed precision metal-film resistors exposed to high voltage (but within ratings) drifting large amounts over time (more than ten times the tolerance band). Visually, they looked perfect. I've also seen metal-film resistors that looked almost perfect visually that were open circuit (due to a nearby EMP event).